# .htaccess rewriterule without changing url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with ReWriteRule in my .htaccess (using wordpress) .
I'm trying to access to the `example.com/forum/?view=forum&id=1` through `example.com/forum/topic/1`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum/topic/([0-9]+)/?$ /forum/?view=forum&id=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I was trying to do it with `forum/?view=forum&id=$1` (w/o slash) and only `http://example.com/forum/?view=forum&id=$1` works, but it changing url (redirecting).

How can i fix that (to see forum topic w/o redirecting)?

Also how should i change all `example.com/forum/?view=forum&id=1`  url's to  `example.com/forum/topic/1` ?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you want to be able to type in the browser?  http://example.com/forum/topic/1 or the other?

Comment: @DeezCashews yes, i want to type in browser  [example.com/forum/topic/1](http://example.com/forum/topic/1) . And without url changing or redirecting see the [example.com/forum/?view=forum&id=1](http://example.com/forum/?view=forum&id=1) page.

Comment: What folder is your .htaccess in?

Comment: @starkeen `/www/example.com/.htaccess`

Comment: I advice you to use the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/forum/topic/([0-9]+)$ /forum/?view=forum&id=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

As for the redirect.  There are certain conditions it will redirect no matter what, like if the hostnames are different (i.e. rewriting http://example.com/forum to go to http://my.othersite.net/forum).   Using this though I don't see why it would.

**EDIT**: Added slash in front of original rewrite rule and example of hostname rewrites that would cause redirects.

Comment: what was changed? removing optional shash from the pattern didn't help.
And what do you mean about "different hostnames"?